# Find the values of a, b, c

Tags: sequences-and-series, integers, rational-numbers

> Given $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{k!}{\Pi_{j=0}^{k}(2j+3)} = a + b\pi^c$$ 
>   where $a$, $c$ - integers, $b$ - is a rational number. Find
>   a, b, c.

Please help or give me a tip on how to approach this kind of problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$S=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{k!}{\prod_{n=0}^k (2n+3)}$$
$$\prod_{n=0}^k (2n+3)=2^k\prod_{n=0}^k \left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right)=2^k\frac{\Gamma(k+1+\frac{3}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{3}{2})}$$

$$S=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma(k+1)\Gamma(\frac{3}{2})}{2^k\Gamma(k+\frac{5}{2})}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\mathfrak{B}(k+1,\frac{3}{2})}{2^k}=\int_0^1\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{t}{2}\right)^k(1-t)^{\frac{1}{2}}dt$$

$$S=\int_0^1\frac{(1-t)^{\frac{1}{2}}}{1-\frac{t}{2}}dt=2\int_0^1\underbrace{\frac{(1-t)^{\frac{1}{2}}}{2-t}}_{t=1-z}dt=2\int_0^1\underbrace{\frac{z^{\frac{1}{2}}}{1+z}}_{z^{\frac{1}{2}}=y}dz$$
$$S=4\int_0^1\frac{y^2}{1+y^2}dy=4-\pi$$

Comment: Nicely done recognizing the bottom as a factorial $\Rightarrow$ (+1)

Comment: @clathratus Thank you :)

Comment: That was really great solution, thank you)

Comment: @Oleh Berehovskyi, you are welcome. Thanks for the positive feedback :)